# How to Manually call a Destructor on a Smart Pointer?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have a `shared_ptr` for an `SDL_Texture` in a game I'm making. I want to use a shared pointer to be able to use the same texture on multiple objects without leaking any memory. I have the shared pointer return from a method which is

```
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture> RenderWindow::loadTexture(const char *filePath) {

    return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>(IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, filePath),
            SDL_DestroyTexture);
}
```

However, when I'm done using the texture in the game, I want to be able to manually call it's destructor, which is `SDL_DestroyTexture` however that doesn't get called when I need it to and it takes up a lot of memory. Is there any way of telling it to call its destructor when I want it to?

Comment: It will be destryed when the reference count goes down to 0. If it's not destryed it means that you still have references to it.

Comment: The whole purpose of `shared_ptr` is to destroy the referenced object ***when all pointers to it are gone***. If you want to destroy the referenced object before that point: 1) don't use shared_ptr, 2) figure out what should all other remaining pointers/referenced to this object should do, after it's destroyed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The smart pointer that gets used on the object is defined in the Game class as `std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture> texture = window.loadTexture("res/images/texture.png")` and that gets copied each time I create a new object, so that smart pointer will always exist.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to do, it's completely unclear. A shared_ptr results in the referenced object's destructor getting invoked only after all shared_ptrs to the referenced object are gone. That's it. That's how shared_ptr works, and that's the only reason to use it. If you don't want for that behavior to happen you'll have to use something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can release the ownership of the object by calling `reset()` on the shared_ptr. If that is the last one holding the pointer, the shared_ptr's deleter member will be used to destroy the object.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset

Comment: If there were any remaining references to the pointer (there won't be when I call it) what would happen when I do `reset()`

Comment: @Gold87 - If there are remaining references (by other `shared_ptr`s) then the destructor for the contained object will not be called.      That is, more or less, the purpose of `shared_ptr` - to keep a managed object alive while any references to it are held.